# Visual studio showing old targeted .net framework even after updated to .net framework 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, migration, .net-framework-version

We are using visual studio 2015 to open class library project. While we were trying to update .net framework of project from 4.5 to 4.7 , csproj file and app.config file get updated and it's started targeting to .net framework 4.7 . but when we opened properties of project and checked application property it's still targeting to old 4.5 .net framework instead of 4.7 .

Comment: Can you retry explaining what you've done, step by step? Also realize that 4.7 was released in 2017, so it's possible that VS 2015 doesn't have it in its dropdown list

Comment: It's available in drop-down list of visual studio 2015 as well. Initially project was targeting to .net framework 4.5 then steps we followed:-
1. Changed targeting framework from 4.5 to 4.7 in application property section by selecting Target Framework option.

Comment: exact problem I'm having - did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click project go to properties and change a project framework to desired version.

Comment: Hi Neo, we followed this way only , but after selecting .net framework 4.7 and update it revert back to previous framework 4.5 automatically.

Comment: Hi Neo. Please try to refrain from adding "hope this helps" or other similar sentiments to your answers. It is entirely a redundant phrase, since no-one posts hoping their work does not help.